# Decreasing whitespace in glyphicon-remove text bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the text to be readable (less white space) in the text of the glyphicon that appears after selecting an option in my dropdown, this is what my code for displaying the glyphicon-remove looks like:

```
<div id="selectedLoanPDivCB" hidden>
Purpose of loan: 
<p id="selectedLoanPurposeCB" name="selectedLoanPurposeCB" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control" value=""></p>
</div>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of how to decrease the amount of whitespace between the words?

EDIT:
I tried without the glyphicon, and the text looks fine.. but I really want to use this glyphicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `word-spacing:0;` to the p tag. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c97cqbkv/)

Comment: I tried, there's no difference, tried using !important aswell incase it was getting overwritten but that didn't work either.. I really don't know what's wrong here. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Coderap could you post all the computed styles for that element.if possible create jsfiddle and check whether it still exists or not.